# Como hacer ternaria en el ORM de Laravel : Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade, artisan

tenia una duda de como manejar mi **ternaria** en *eloquent*.

Os comento:

Tengo tres tablas:

*- Mundos*

*- Razas*

*- Clases*

*- Personajes* (Para explicar mejor la situacion meto esta)

Las **relaciones** son las siguientes:

1 Mundo - N Clases 
1 Mundo - N Razas 
1 Personaje - 1 Clase 
1 Personaje - 1 Raza

Por tanto **he creado la nueva tabla** *mundo_raza_clase*:

La cual contiene (*id,mundo,raza,clase*)
Y esta sea **la que se reelacione con personaje**

Bueno una vez explicado eso pasemos con **Laravel**

---

El **CLI** usado es ***artisan***

Primero: he creado una **modelo con migracion** de **mundo**:

> php artisan make:model Mundo -m

Segundo:  he creado una **modelo con migracion** de **clase**:

> php artisan make:model Clase -m

Tercero: he creado una **modelo con migracion** de **raza**:

> php artisan make:model Raza -m

Hasta aqui *guay*. Ahora bien, para crear el ***(modelo)* y migracion de *mundo_raza_clase*** me surge las siguientes **dudas:**

1. Para la **ternaria** tambien tengo que crear **migracion y modelo** ??
   Por que como realmente no es un objeto del tipo `$usuario->nombre`,no se si me explico. Realmente es una tabla *pivote* por tanto no la voy a tener que usar en mis template con *blade* simplemente es un **puente** para sacar informacion entre tablas.

   2. Esta duda es mas general en cuanto a **relaciones en laravel**, me explico,  yo hasta ahora hacia las **relaciones** en las migraciones (*porque fue lo que encontre por varias paginas, lo aplique y no me fue mal la verdad*) pero por otras muchas paginas se ve que las relaciones se hacen a nivel de modelo (**Ej:** `$this->belongsToMany("Employment", 'employee_project')`, *etc..*)

Comment: Porque crear **mundo_raza_clase**? no lo veo necesario, si la relacion es: 1 Mundo - N Clases, 1 Mundo - N Razas, lo unico que tendrias que hacer es que tu tabla Rasas tenga el id_mundo y de igual forma tu tabla Clases debe de tener el id_mundo, y en tu tabla personaje deberias tener los id`s de raza y clase, ** No veo necesario la tabla que deseas hacer.**

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!